# Есть DataGridView в WPF. Необходимо записать результат умножения в ячейку

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<DataGrid x:Name="aprasDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource aprasViewSource}}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFB5C9D6" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" HeadersVisibility="Column" CellEditEnding="aprasDataGrid_CellEditEnding" Margin="1,296,12,174" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" RowEditEnding="aprasDataGrid_RowEditEnding">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="aprasymasidColumn" Binding="{Binding aprasymasid}" Header="aprasymasid" Width="SizeToHeader" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="vizitasidColumn" Binding="{Binding vizitasid}" Header="vizitasid" Width="SizeToHeader" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dantisnColumn" Binding="{Binding dantisn}" Header="Dantis" Width="SizeToHeader">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                            <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="Dantis_LostFocus"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="partnColumn" Binding="{Binding partn}" Header="Part" Width="SizeToHeader">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                            <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="Part_LostFocus"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="kiekisColumn" Binding="{Binding kiekis}" Header="Kiekis" Width="Auto">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                            <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="Kiekis_LostFocus"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="sumaColumn" Binding="{Binding suma}" Header="F.kaina" Width="Auto">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                            <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="Qty_LostFocus"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="sumasColumn" Header="Suma" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="paslaugaColumn" Binding="{Binding paslauga}" Header="Paslauga" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="kainaColumn" Binding="{Binding kaina}" Header="P.kaina" Width="SizeToHeader" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="grupecColumn" Binding="{Binding grupec}" Header="Grupė" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="paslaugosidColumn" Binding="{Binding paslaugosid}" Header="paslaugosid" Width="SizeToHeader" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="grupeidColumn" Binding="{Binding grupeid}" Header="grupeid" Width="SizeToHeader" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Данные получаем:

((DataRowView)aprasDataGrid.SelectedItems[0]).Row["kiekis"].ToString();
((DataRowView)aprasDataGrid.SelectedItems[0]).Row["suma"].ToString();

Как программным путем изменить значение sumasColumn?

Comment: А почему вы хотите подсчитать произведение во View? У вас же специально для этого есть VM.

Comment: если данные в DataTable, то в них есть составные/вычисляемые столбцы -- см. [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Stack: Круто, не знал. Почему бы не как ответ?

Comment: Потому как данные в таблицу заносятся сразу после редактирования и не подгружаются из таблицы после редактирования. Только при открытии формы. Есть на то причины.

Answer (score 1):

1. Поле в модели элемента коллекции.

   ```
   public double Suma
   {
       get { return kiekis * suma; }
   }
   ```

В этом случае надо вызывать PropertyChanged() каждый раз, когда изменяется `kiekis` или `suma`, чтобы это корректно отображалось в интерфейсе

2. Конвертер. Обычный, не мультиконвертер.

   ```
   <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="sumasColumn" Header="Suma" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True>
       <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
           <Binding Path="." UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
               <Binding.Converter>
                   <myNamespace:SumConverter />
               </Binding.Converter>
           </Binding>
       </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
   </DataGridTextColumn>
   ```

Код конвертера:

```
public class SumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var item = (MyType) value;
        return item.kiekis * item.suma;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вариант с конвертером неправильный: конвертер не будет вызываться, когда свойства поменяются.

Comment: спасибо, поправил

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, всё равно не сработает. Ваша привязка идёт не к свойствам, а к самому VM-объекту, а значит, изменения нужных _свойств_ `Binding` просто не увидит.

Comment: Сработает. Будет определённый оверхед, так как будет вызываться конвертер при каждом PropertyChanged источника, но так как это и так не лучший вариант - ничего страшного.

Comment: Ну, не верите мне — вот вам код, пробуйте сами. http://pastebin.com/xwqUn7kG

Comment: `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` там нет. завтра добавлю и попробую :)

Comment: Добавил, ничего не поменялось, вроде бы.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, простое решение, quick and dirty, через конвертер:

```
class MultiplyingConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.Cast<double>().Aggregate((x, y) => x * y);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter,
                                CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Имея такой конвертер, вы можете по идее просто сказать

```
<!-- в ресурсах -->
<local:MultiplyingConverter x:Key="mult"/>
```

```
<!-- в DataGrid -->
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="sumasColumn" Header="Suma" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource mult}">
            <Binding Path="kiekis"/>
            <Binding Path="suma"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

(Код не тестировал, надеюсь, что скомпилируется.)

---

Но правильным решением наверное было бы вычислять всё же нужные величины не на уровне презентации (View), а на уровне бизнес-логики (VM). При этом вы бы просто получили в вашей VM ещё одно поле, и привязались бы к нему.

Comment: Не работает. Наверное все же придется решать через VM

Comment: @OscarOS: Что значит «не работает»? Покажите код.

Comment: decimal result = values.Cast<decimal>().Aggregate((x, y) => x * y);
            MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
            return result;

Comment: Сумма вычисляется, но... результат не  отображается.

Comment: <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="sumasColumn" Header="Suma" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource mult}">
                                <Binding Path="kiekis"/>
                                <Binding Path="suma"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

Comment: в вашем коде поменял только <double> на <decimal>

Comment: @OscarOS: То есть messagebox показывается?

Comment: @OscarOS: А если написать return result.ToString()?

Comment: return result.ToString();

Comment: Да!!! Только что пришел к тому же выводу!

Comment: Теперь все работает ))) Спасибо!!!

Comment: @OscarOS: Вот и хорошо :) Пожалуйста!